# Unable to create connection to SFTP using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-storage

I am using azure storage SFTP service and trying to connect to it using data factory, but when creating a linked service using sftp connector it giving below mentioned error.  I tried using password and SSH key both arent working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ9i6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use following configuration to connect SFTP enabled blob using Azure data factory.**

```
Host : storage-acc-name.blob.core.windows.net
User name : storage-acc-name.container-name.username(of local user)[if home directory is not specified]/storage-acc-name.username(of local user)[if home directory is specified]
password : you are getting while creating local user
```

**Successful connection:**

[image]

Comment: This is correct - removing everything the "@" and everything before it from your host value should correct the problem.